# ISA 2006 Log Analyzer

Tags: isa-server

We have been using Internet Access Monitor in the past to analyze our ISA logs.

This is now playing up (inconsistent data when comparing to logs from within ISA Server Management.

Any suggestions on what I should be using instead for this?

In particular we are trying to see a staff's bandwidth usage by source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an aside: Log analysis tools that don't understand ISA Server will tend to overcharge users, particularly because they don't include/exclude data counts based on the [object source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb838824.aspx#Objectsourcelogvalues) log values.

If you're OK with the ISP model (have a cache, charge many people for downloads even from the cache, profit!) then this might not be a disadvantage :)